# How to get cases to work

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am trying to answer a question in which I have to use cases in visual basic.

The question is:

Write a program that asks the user for the number of hours worked this week and their hourly rate of pay. The program is to calculate the grass pay. If the number of hours worked is greater than 40, the extra hours are paid at 1.5 times the rate. The program should display an error message if the number of hours worked is not in the range 0 to 60.

Here is the code I wrote, any ideas on what went wrong would be greatly appreciated.

```
Console.WriteLine("This will calculate the gross profit from the hours you work and the hourly pay")
    Console.WriteLine("Your work hours can not be under 0 or above 60, 
    if you work above 40 hours the extra hours will be 1.5 times the original")

    Console.Write("Please enter the hours you work a week: ")
    Dim hours As Integer = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.Write("Please enter the hourly pay you get: ")
    Dim hourlyPay As Decimal = Console.ReadLine()

    Dim message As String = "Your gross pay per week is: £"

    Dim weeklyPay As Decimal

    Select Case hours
        Case 0 < hours < 40
            weeklyPay = hours * hourlyPay
        Case hours > 40 And hours < 60
            weeklypay = ((40 * hourlyPay) + ((hours - 40) * (hourlyPay * 1.5)))
        Case hours < 0 Or hours > 60
            message = "Sorry the hours you entered are above the range try again"
    End Select

    Console.WriteLine(message & weeklyPay.ToString("N2"))
    Console.ReadLine()
```

Comment: How are we supposed to know what went wrong?

Comment: [Select Case Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/select-case-statement) and [Select Case Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/select-case-statement) also please read [ask] and take the [tour].  Also turn on Option Strict

Comment: What if I type "ABC" for anyone of your inputs? Remember integers/decimals are not strings and you shouldn't relay on the compiler to make things easier for you. Option Strict On

Comment: Also note, that for instance _exactly_ 40 or 60 hours are not handled at all. Learn the condition operators <= and >=.

Answer (score 2):

`Select` works on a first come first served basis, by testing for conditions and handling them in order you can eliminate each condition so that all that remains is the 'default' condition.

```
Select Case hours
    Case Is > 60
        message = "Sorry the hours you entered are above the range try again"
    Case Is < 0
        message = "Sorry the hours you entered are below the range try again"
    Case Is > 40
        weeklypay = ((40 * hourlyPay) + ((hours - 40) * (hourlyPay * 1.5)))
    Case Else
        weeklyPay = hours * hourlyPay
End Select
```

[MSDN - Select...Case Statement (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/select-case-statement)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to solve it:

```
    Console.WriteLine("This will calculate the gross profit from the hours you work and the hourly pay")     'sends the message of what this program does
    Console.WriteLine("Your work hours can not be under 0 or above 60, 
    if you work above 40 hours the extra hours will be 1.5 times the original")                              'explains the boundaries and conditions
    Console.ReadLine()
    Console.Write("Please enter the hours you work a week: ")                                                'asks for the hours worked
    Dim hours As Integer = Console.ReadLine()                                                                'declares hours as an integer and sets it's value for what the user enters 
    Console.Write("Please enter the hourly rate of pay: ")                                                   'asks for the hourly rate of pay
    Dim hourlyPay As Decimal = Console.ReadLine()                                                            'declares hourlyPay as a decimal and sets it's value for what the user enters
    Dim message As String = "Your gross pay per week is: £"                                                  'declares message as a string and sets it's value to tell the user what their pay is - this will be useful later
    Dim weeklyPay As Decimal                                                                                 'declares weekly pay as a decimal
    Select Case hours                                                                                        'An if statement would complicated to use so, i used a select case
        Case 0 To 40                                                                                         'when hours are between 0 and 40, then the weekly pay is normal (hourly rate * hours) 
            weeklyPay = hours * hourlyPay
        Case 40 To 60                                                                                        'however when hours are above 40, then the extra hours (hours - 40) are paid at a higher rate (1.5 times)
            weeklyPay = ((40 * hourlyPay) + ((hours - 40) * (hourlyPay * 1.5)))
        Case < 0                                                                                             'when hours are under the boundary of 0 then send the error message
            message = "Sorry the hours you entered are under the range try again "
        Case > 60                                                                                            'when hours are over the boundary of 60 then send the error message
            message = "Sorry the hours you entered are above the range try again "
    End Select
    Console.WriteLine(message & weeklyPay.ToString("N2"))                                                    'this sends the message across to the user and their pay
    Console.ReadLine()                                                                                       'stops the program from terminating
```